# Constants in Interface

Tags: java

I know there were a lot of questions about putting constants into interfaces, and that is a bad practice.

But I have a question, what if I have a class, where I want to define some sets of constants, but I want to have them in groups, is it a bad practice to have interface/class inside a class and define constants in there, so my constants are grouped?

e.g.

```
    public class MyClass{

    public final class A {
     public static final String A = "a" ;
    }
    public final class B {
     public static final String B = "b";
    }
    ....
    }
```

Comment: Why user interfaces at all? That's totally not their purpose. Use nested classes if you want to group your constants.

Comment: ok, I'll use nested classes, thanks

Comment: In this case syntactically there really wouldn't be much different outside of being able to implement the nested interfaces

Comment: It's a good practice as long as your class doesn't grow too much. Large constants class usually are a bad design and can also cause performance issues when developing. See Michael Borgwardt comment at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/171539/using-nested-public-classes-to-organize-constants

Comment: it's not a performance issue @MarcoA.Hernandez: he's stating it requires recompilation when utilizing external constants and that this could slow _development_ time (not performance). Though I disagree with that point, I do agree that it can be messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can have nested class to group the constants. It's really not a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

the question leads to a misleading. From my point of view the necessity to group constants is related to the fact that they regards different classes and so they must be putted int the correct classes; in other words this question can be an alarm about a not perfectly correct class design.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but constants are related to the class, so I do not see reason why to create another not nested class and put the constants there.